# BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar, when I give a timestamp argument

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

In my Java application, I used to have a sql query such as below :

```
INSERT INTO "KPI_MEASURE" (
        id,
        created_at,
        kpi_project_id,
        kpi_frequency_id,
        kpi_metric_id,
        branch,
        value
    )
SELECT
    nextval('"KPI_MEASURE_ID_seq"'::regclass),
    now(),
    kpi_measure.kpi_project_id,
    kpi_measure.kpi_frequency_id,
    kpi_measure.kpi_metric_id ,
    kpi_measure.branch ,
    sum(kpi_measure.value)
FROM "KPI_MEASURE" kpi_measure
    INNER JOIN "KPI_METRIC" kpi_metric                      ON kpi_measure.kpi_metric_id = kpi_metric.id
    INNER JOIN "KPI_PROJECT" kpi_project                    ON kpi_measure.kpi_project_id = kpi_project.id
    INNER JOIN "KPI_AGGREGATION_PROJECT" kpi_agg_project    ON kpi_project.name = kpi_agg_project.child_project_name
    WHERE kpi_metric.aggregated = false
GROUP BY kpi_measure.branch, kpi_measure.kpi_metric_id, kpi_measure.kpi_project_id, kpi_project.name, kpi_measure.kpi_frequency_id;
```

I executed that sql, with `jdbcTemplate.update`, and it worked.
But recently I changed the value `now()` by an argument: `:today_date`, I give that argument with my code:

```
Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
parameters.put(TODAY_DATE, today); // TODAY_DATE = today_date

jdbcTemplate.update(sql, parameters);
```

But now, it creates an error:

> org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar
>
> ...
> nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: No hstore extension installed.

I don't see why it's an error, since it's what I was told to do, when we want to add argument with the jdbc query.

---

## Edit:

The column data type is `timestamp without time zone`, while the `today` variable is of `String` type.
I guess, I should have used `Timestamp`, so I changed my code:

```
Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
parameters.put(TODAY_DATE, new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis())); // TODAY_DATE = today_date

jdbcTemplate.update(sql, parameters);
```

Now I only have the the error

> "PSQLException: No hstore extension installed."

Maybe, I need to add an hstore, but I can't seem to understand why.

Comment: what is datatype of today ? what is cloumn's data type ?

Comment: There is a difference between the result of the SQL function `NOW()` and a Java `Object`. If you want to store complex objects, do what the error message says and install the hstore extension. Before, the data type of that column was `DATE` or maybe `DATETIME` and now it is an object with probably several attributes.

Comment: I always used timestamp, except in this case, but I changed my variable today to timestamp, but I still get that error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using JdbcTenmplate with named parameters, but JdbcTemplate supports only positioned parameters (?). Replace JdbcTemplate  with [NamedParameterJdbcTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html) or rewrite your query as:

```
INSERT INTO "KPI_MEASURE" (
        id,
        created_at,
        kpi_project_id,
        kpi_frequency_id,
        kpi_metric_id,
        branch,
        value
    )
SELECT
    nextval('"KPI_MEASURE_ID_seq"'::regclass),
    ?,
    kpi_measure.kpi_project_id,
    kpi_measure.kpi_frequency_id,
    kpi_measure.kpi_metric_id ,
    kpi_measure.branch ,
    sum(kpi_measure.value)
FROM "KPI_MEASURE" kpi_measure
    INNER JOIN "KPI_METRIC" kpi_metric                      ON kpi_measure.kpi_metric_id = kpi_metric.id
    INNER JOIN "KPI_PROJECT" kpi_project                    ON kpi_measure.kpi_project_id = kpi_project.id
    INNER JOIN "KPI_AGGREGATION_PROJECT" kpi_agg_project    ON kpi_project.name = kpi_agg_project.child_project_name
    WHERE kpi_metric.aggregated = false
GROUP BY kpi_measure.branch, kpi_measure.kpi_metric_id, kpi_measure.kpi_project_id, kpi_project.name, kpi_measure.kpi_frequency_id;
```

and call `jdbcTemplate.update(sql, new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));`